# Django: send emails in local language

Tags: django

I'm trying to send a language in local language. Let's say, a user fills up the registration form on the French website, I would like to send him an email in French.

I have tried with translation.override but it didn't work. What's the correct way of sending localized emails?

```
subject = _('Please Activate Your Account')
email_context = {'domain': current_site.domain,
                 'uid': reset_uid,
                 'token': token,}

html_body = render_to_string('email/activation-request-email.html', email_context)
text_body = render_to_string('email/activation-request-email.txt', email_context)
send_mail(subject=subject, message=text_body, from_email='no-reply@example.com', recipient_list=[user.email], html_message=html_body)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow Django's [Internationalization in templates code guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code).
it is very helpful, everything you need is there.

Comment: My website is already localized. I have the problem in render_to_string method. I render an html to be sent over email. I need to use the translated email.